# Issue working with SAML 2.0 Azure AD with Tomcat. How to install Azure Certificate on Tomcat

Tags: azure, tomcat, saml

84663 [main] ERROR org.springframework.security.saml.trust.MetadataCredentialResolver  - PKIX path construction failed for untrusted credential: [subjectName='CN=Microsoft Azure Federated SSO Certificate']: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

84687 [main] ERROR org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.SignatureValidationFilter  - Signature trust establishment failed for metadata entry

84687 [main] ERROR org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider  - Error filtering metadata from

org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.FilterException: Signature trust establishment failed for metadata entry
at org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.SignatureValidationFilter.verifySignature(SignatureValidationFilter.java:327) ~[opensaml-2.6.6.jar:?]

Doing it first time don't know how to import SAML azure cert on Tomcat and how to configure a specific bean.

Any help would be appreciated.